# Console2 run command on start

Tags: console2

I run this command in cmd:

```
console2 -t MyTab -r ipconfig
```

Should this command auto run ipconfig after console opens MyTab? It doesn't for me. It doesn't even without -t option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `filename of the shell` and `its parameters` need to be specified explicitly, like `CMD.exe /K` (or `%COMSPEC% /K`), in either  
`Console Settings -> Console -> Shell`  
or  
`Console Settings -> Tabs -> MyTab -> Shell` .

Comment: What if I want to run different commands on for one tab?

Comment: Just made the suggestion a bit clearer, my bad. To be on the safe side, `place the commands` which you would like Console2 to run `in double quotes`, like `console2 -t MyTab -r "ipconfig & dir C:\Windows | more"`

Comment: Unfortunately you suggestion does not work, have you tried it?

Comment: Yap, it's triple-checked before being posted. It may sound daft, but I just wonder if there is `a tab called MyTab in your Console Settings -> Tabs`. If not, Console2 won't launch properly.

Comment: Yes there is a MyTab, there is nothing in Shell field and in Startup dir there is a dir that opens up when I run: console2 -t MyTab -r "ipconfig" but ipconfig command does not run.

Comment: The shell field in the tab settings has to contain "%COMSPEC% /K", this is what user29318 was trying to say. This tripped me up too.